# Perl script that takes linux path as input from the user till a directory and need to get the output of all the directories with common name

Tags: perl, scripting

I have written Perl script that takes linux path as input from user until a certain directory and prints all the directories inside that which have the common name for example,
if user input is `/user/images/mobile_photos/` inside `mobile_photos` I have a list of directories that start with `image_` like `image_user_1,image_user_2,...,image_user_10` and inside each directory there is quality of image like `best,good,bad` as a string in a file `quality.txt`. Now I need to get the list of these directories inside a file with the quality of the images next to directory name.

Actual path for one example

```
/user/images/mobile_photos/image_user_1/quality.txt
```

The user should give input as

```
/user/images/mobile_photos/
```

The required output inside `temp.txt` is

```
image_user_1 good
image_user_2 bad
image_user_3 best
image_user_4 best 
.
.
.
image_user_10 bad
```

Below is the code attached just for image quality being good

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $path = <STDIN>;
 my $dir = system ("ls -d $path/image_*/quality.txt "good" > temp.txt");
 print "$dir";
 exit(0);
```

But I am getting the terminal output as `/user/images/mobile_photos/` and `temp.txt` being empty.

Comment: Why the system call?

Comment: `system` returns the exit status of the command you gave it. Not the output. Which means your print will be something like `0`. You will see the output printed to the terminal, but it is not part of your program.

Comment: You do realize that your quoting is broken when you use double quotes around `"good"`? That should have made your program exit with a syntax error or similar.

Comment: "_there is quality of image like `best`,`good`,`bad` as a string in a file `quality.txt`_" -- how is it "in" the file?  The only word in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using low level [opendir](http://p3rl.org/opendir) and [readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir):

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

chomp( my $path = <STDIN> );
opendir my $dir, $path or die "Can't open $path: $!";
while (my $dir = readdir $dir) {
    next unless -d "$path/$dir" && $dir =~ /^image_/;

    if (-f "$path/$dir/quality.txt") {
        open my $q, '<', "$path/$dir/quality.txt"
            or die "Can't open $dir/quality.txt: $!";
        chomp( my $quality = <$q> );
        say "$dir\t$quality";
    } else {
        warn "quality.txt not found in $dir.\n";
    }
}
```

Or using [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) (highly recommended!):

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Path::Tiny qw{ path };

chomp( my $path = <STDIN> );
$path = path($path);
die "Not a directory\n" unless $path->is_dir;

for my $dir ($path->children(qr/^image_/)) {
    next unless $dir->is_dir;

    my $quality_file = $dir->child('quality.txt');
    if ($quality_file->is_file) {
        chomp( my $quality = $quality_file->slurp );
        say "$dir\t$quality";
    } else {
        warn "quality.txt not found in $dir.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (-f "$path/$dir/quality.txt") { open my $q, '<', "$path/$dir/quality.txt" or die "Can't open $dir/quality.txt: $!"; chomp( my $quality = <$q> ); say "$dir\t$quality"; } else { warn "quality.txt not found in $dir.\n"; } }` Can I send the $dir\t$quality output list into a file instead of displaying it?

Comment: @kcv9712: Can't you just redirect the output of the whole script to a file?

Answer (score 2):

No reason to go out to the `system` for this.  It's only far more complicated that way, and there is an extra challenge of getting all the quotes and escapes right. Instead, here is an example of how to do it entirely in Perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;                          # path
use File::Spec::Functions qw(splitdir);
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';              # glob

my $path = shift // die "Usage: $0 path\n";

my @dirs = grep { -d } glob "$path/image_*";

# Read a sole word from a file in each dir, save list to a file
my $out_file = 'temp.txt';
open my $fh_out, '>', $out_file or die "Can't open $out_file: $!";
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    print $fh_out 
        (splitdir($dir))[-1], 
        ' ',
        path("$dir/quality.txt")->slurp;  # has a linefeed
}
close $fh_out or warn "Error closing $out_file: $!";
```

The builtin [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) has a small set of metacharacters like the shell's. I use [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob), which replaces the builtin `glob`, as it also handles spaces in filenames. I also use the handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) to "slurp" a file (read it whole into a string) and [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Spec::Functions) to get the last part of the path, as wanted for output.

There are of course yet other ways to read directories and select entries.

Comment: I am getting an error which states that Can't locate feature.pm in @INC

Comment: @kcv9712 ouch ... that's either a very very old Pelr verion (?), or the install is broken/crippled in some way.  Anyway, I use here only `say` "feature," which is merely a `print` with a newline added.  So instead of `say "...";` do `print "...\n";` and remove (or comment out) the `use feature...;` statement

Comment: @kcv9712 Or, perhaps you need to add that `#! /usr/bin/perl` as the first line

Comment: I have added it yet I am getting the same error

Comment: @kcv9712 OK.  Then either your install is broken in some way or your Perl version is very very old.  The "feature" pragma was added to [Perl version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history) 5.10.0, released in late 2007.   (Can see the version with `perl -v`.) If you indeed have a version that old I'd suggest to upgrade.

Comment: @kcv9712  [cont'd] ... As for this answer just remove the `use feature 'say';` line (I realize now that I never actually use `say` in this answer!  I include it by habit, as one normally does print...)  Now I'm curious -- how does the other answer work then, since they also have `use feature` (and use their `say`)?  The difference is that they have the `#! ...` ("shebang") line but you say you add it here and it still fails ... I'm confused

Comment: (added the line `#! /usr/bin/perl`)